# How to pass custom code_verifier on msal 2.0 for Azure B2C?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, msal-react

Generally, MSAL 2.0 auto-generates the code and code_verifier by itself.
But Here, I have my custom flow when half part is done on another code i.e. to generate code_challenge.
But When I call from front-end I am unable to find a way that I can pass my own code_verifier to get a token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use acquireTokenByCode method of useMsal to get token from B2C using code.

Header

```
const { instance, inProgress } = useMsal();
```

Code

```
instance.acquireTokenByCode(...tokenreq,{code:'123456',codeVerifier: 'ABCDSRIDD'})
```

Thank you